# How to search data in two phalcon tables

Tags: find, phalcon

Someone could explain me  How to search data in two phalcon tables:

I have this query:

```
$Q = $this->request->getPost("data");
$phql = 'SELECT b.idbank,b.name,m.description,m.date
         FROM bank b
         inner join movement m on b.idbank=m.idbank
         WHERE b.estado = 1 and b.name like "%'.$Q.'%"  or m.description like "%'.$Q.'%" 
         Order by b.idbank desc
         ';

$bank = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
```

There would be some way to do it this way:

```
$Q = $this->request->getPost("data");
$bank = Bank::find([
    "name like '%:dato:%'",
    "bind" => [
        "dato" => $Q
    ]
]);

$mov = $bank->getmovement([
    "description like '%:dato:%'",
    "bind" => [
        "dato" => $Q
    ]
]);
$bank = $mov->bank;
```

I actually do not know how to do it.

What I did is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the percents from the condition placeholder to your bind parameters. Your first query reworked:

```
$bank = Bank::find([
    "name like :dato:",
    "bind" => [
        "dato" => '%'. $Q .'%'
    ]
]);
```

More examples in **[the Documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.0/reference/models.html#binding-parameters)**.